# Array gets nil GCD

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

When I run this code it works fine but when I run it in `dispatch_async` it gets error in tableViews function `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
    self.data = self.dataOfJson("http://192.168.1.100/practice/studentCourseSelection.php?ID=\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentUser")!)")
    self.RefreshTableView()
}

func RefreshTableView()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
 func dataOfJson(url:String) -> NSArray
{
    var jsonArray : NSMutableArray = []

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string : url)!)
    jsonArray = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray



     return jsonArray
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try change `return self.data.count` to `return self.data.count ?? 0`

Comment: Show your code! What is `self.dataOfJson`? How does your code implement `numberOfRowsInSection` and the other two Big Questions?

Comment: when self.data is nil, calling count to nil cause EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION RED ERROR. you have to check isn't it nil

Comment: @JosuéH. - I think you mean `return data?.count ?? 0`. Without that `?`, the implicitly unwrapping of `data` will still take place.

Comment: matt numberOfRowsInsSection just returns  data.count

Comment: @AbdulWaheed - That's what we're saying: `data` is obviously an implicitly unwrapped optional that you're updating asynchronously. So the first time the `UITableViewDataSource` methods are called, it's probably still `nil`, causing the crash you describe. But if you use `return data?.count ?? 0`, that will tell the tableview that if `data` is still `nil`, then there are no rows to be shown on the table yet. Later, when `data` is updated asynchronously, you can `tableView.reloadData()`, at which point `numberOfRowsInSection` can now return a meaningful `count`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify `self.data` on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED, 0)) {
    let data = self.dataOfJson("http://192.168.1.100/practice/studentCourseSelection.php?ID=\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("currentUser")!)")
    self.RefreshTableView(data)    
}

func RefreshTableView(data: ??) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
        self.data = data
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked.. i made some modifications.. But Thanks a lot